# Unable to Run Python Code in Terminal Visual studios code(EntryNotFound Unable to read file)

Tags: python, python-3.9

[FilenotFoundError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ppfY.jpg)

Currently trying to run some python code on vscode but I got this error also for some reason I'm not getting any output in the terminal, can't type anything in it either what should I do?

[NoTerminalOutputInVScode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR5b3.jpg)

[launcherTimedOut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BIOI.jpg)
I tried to debug my python file and vsc would return this.

[launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlEPN.jpg)
This be what my launch.json file looks like.

Comment: you can always try to switch to another ide like pycharm

Comment: The path in the error suggests a `settings.json` cannot be found. Have you tried to create one using `Shift Ctrl + P` and typing 'Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)' ?

Comment: @marcel h Ya I just did that the problem persist I tried running installing extensions like code runner which helps me run code in the output but the problem is its unable to accept input, yes I also checked the box in preferences>settings for code runner run in terminal, I just get a blank terminal. If I try debugging my python code it will say timed out waiting for launcher to launch

Comment: @rv.kvetch tbf man ya u might be right I initially was using pycharm before I tried switching to visual studios code but i ran into this problem :( 
I initially only used vsc for like web dev stuff HTML,CSS,js